# My facebook blocking ACL has stopped working

Tags: cisco, router, access-control-list

This probably very simple.  This was setup before I arrived, and has been working to block facebook.  I recently eliminated some static port forwarding on this `2691` (as in, I don't think anything else has changed), and now facebook is once again accessible.

Why is this list not doing what it seems like it should be doing (and *was* doing)?  Would an extended outbound ACL be more appropriate (I think that would have been my thought if I had been tasked with creating this in the first place)?  Something different?

I've included below what I believe are the relevant parts of the config.

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address my.pub.ip.add my.ip.add.msk
 ip access-group 1 in
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto

access-list 1 deny   69.171.224.0 0.0.31.255
access-list 1 deny   74.119.76.0 0.0.3.255
access-list 1 deny   204.15.20.0 0.0.3.255
access-list 1 deny   66.220.144.0 0.0.15.255
access-list 1 deny   69.63.176.0 0.0.15.255
access-list 1 permit any

ip nat inside source list 105 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
access-list 105 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.8.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 105 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 105 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

---

**EDIT**

ACL is once again blocking Facebook.  Here is the new definition for those interested...

```
access-list 1 deny   66.220.144.0 0.0.7.255
access-list 1 deny   66.220.152.0 0.0.7.255
access-list 1 deny   69.63.176.0 0.0.7.255
access-list 1 deny   69.63.176.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 deny   69.63.184.0 0.0.7.255
access-list 1 deny   69.171.224.0 0.0.15.255
access-list 1 deny   69.171.239.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 deny   69.171.240.0 0.0.15.255
access-list 1 deny   69.171.255.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 deny   74.119.76.0 0.0.3.255
access-list 1 deny   173.252.64.0 0.0.31.255
access-list 1 deny   173.252.70.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 deny   173.252.96.0 0.0.31.255
access-list 1 deny   204.15.20.0 0.0.3.255
access-list 1 permit any
```

Comment: Have you tried diff'ing your old config and this new one?

Comment: @longneck- I store the config on an internal wiki.  When I side-by-side the two versions, the only differences (besides dates and config sizes etc) are the elimination of the static port forwarding routes.  I can add to the question... just thought it'd make the question too long.

Comment: I'm not so sure the router is the place for filtering. Do you have a web filter appliance?

Comment: @jscott, We do not.  The network has kind of grown organically as the company has grown, without an IT person for some years, and my budget is... well, zero :)

Comment: @Josh: Facebook is using more addresses than that. See http://bgp.he.net/AS32934#_prefixes. They're also using IPv6.

Comment: @petrus, thanks.  So, at this point, I'm thinking a second question may be in order to get some input on how best to block facebook with the hardware I have access to.

Comment: @Josh: Just edit your access-list 1 to add the ranges announced bu AS32934.

Comment: @petrus, Thank you for that link.  Those additional addresses did the trick.  If you want to change your comment to an answer...

Comment: @Josh Please post that as an Answer to the Question, and accept it when you can. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisS, I certainly will, but I thought I'd give petrus the opportunity to post it since he pointed me to the proper IP addresses.  I pinged him in the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is operating their own network, hence announcing their address ranges to other networks (i.e. internet) with [BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP).

Using a public [BGP looking glass](https://www.google.com/search?q=bgp%20looking%20glass) or a direct bgp feed to your router, it's possible to know what are those ranges by looking at the routes that have AS32934 (Facebook [Autonomous system number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_Number)) in the path.

While this can be very convenient (null-routing all AS32934 prefixes), not everyone has BGP knowledge and one can just look at [the prefixes announced by Facebook](http://bgp.he.net/AS32934#_prefixes) on HurricaneElectric's website. However, this list should be manually updated as Facebook can add new prefixes.

Using this list, it's really easy to block Facebook using a simple access-list on the router.

As Facebook is now using ipv6 as well, you should also add an ipv6 access-list on the FastEthernet0/0 interface with [the few network announced](http://bgp.he.net/AS32934#_prefixes6) if your network is ipv6-enabled.

Beware though, if Facebook uses a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) like Akamai, the addresses of the servers (reverse proxies/caches) might be in the CDN's ip address ranges, not in Facebook's.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect facebook simply added some new IP address space.  Port forwarding or lack thereof should have no effect that I can think of on your inbound access list.   Where did you get that list of IP addresses for Facebook?

Comment: That is certainly possible.  Like I said, it was set up before I arrived, and it has been working.  I have seen that list of addresses posted elsewhere, though I can't remember where off the top of my head.

Comment: Found one of the [places](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/block-access-to-a-web-site-using-the-cisco-ios/6115879) I saw this list.  They're included in one of the comments at the end of the post.